# Find element by XPath with attribute name within square brackets

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I need to build a XPath with attributes within square brackets. This is from Power BI report:

HTML Element:

```
<exploration-container [view-model]="viewModel.explorationContainer" [exploration-container-options]="explorationContainerOptions" ng-version="8.2.6">
```

Tried following but did not work:

```
//exploration-container[@[exploration-container-options]='explorationContainerOptions']
```

Comment: Wont [ in attribute names make the xml invalid

Comment: May be, but any alternative to above problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `name()` to work with the attribute name

Direct match

```
//exploration-container[@*[name()='[exploration-container-options]']='explorationContainerOptions']
```

Contains

```
//exploration-container[@*[contains(name(), exploration-container-options)]='explorationContainerOptions']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS if possible.
Just a simple \ before [
for example

```
//exploration-container[\[exploration-container-options]='explorationContainerOptions']
```

Hope this might help you.